# Does Android send a notification to the application when its cache is deleted?

Tags: android, caching, notifications, android-notifications

In Android, is there a notification sent by the OS to the application when its cache is being deleted and the application is running?

With the application running, it is possible to put it in background, go to the settings menu, manage applications and clear the cache, then go back to the running application. It might be important to know it to flush any variable related to the cache state.

If there is no notification sent, I guess I will have no choice but to check the consistency of the cache each time that the application comes to foreground.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it sends a notification to your App.

However, if the cache is cleared it would be very simple to check in your onResume() function. Simply check whether it has any files in it. If there are no files in it, then your cache was cleared. You could doubly verify this by creating a file when your App starts that you can check for the existence of in onResume().